CSS width varies arbitrarily
I was working on a website when I noticed that the width of the pseudo elements I use as borders varies for some reason.

I have provided a minimal demo here.


.filters {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  /* margin-bottom: 0; */
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.filters>* {
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

.filters>*:not(:first-child)::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}


/* This solves the problem for some reason */

#narrow>*:not(:first-child)::before {
  width: 0.8px
}


/* This too, but only if you set the margin on the bottom of the filters to 0, see comment above */

#margin {
  margin-inline: auto;
}


/* This too */


/* This makes the last element wider instead */

#font {
  margin-inline: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif
}


/*
Sometimes the element that is wider changes after zooming in and out. I am starting to believe this has something to do with pixel placement on the screen. Maybe this effect occurs if an element is "between" two physical pixels and thus "takes up" both. 
*/
<div class="filters">
  <div>
    What
  </div>
  <div>
    is
  </div>
  <div>
    going
  </div>
  <div>
    on?
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filters" id="narrow">
  <div>
    What
  </div>
  <div>
    is
  </div>
  <div>
    going
  </div>
  <div>
    on?
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filters" id="margin">
  <div>
    What
  </div>
  <div>
    is
  </div>
  <div>
    going
  </div>
  <div>
    on?
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filters" id="font">
  <div>
    What
  </div>
  <div>
    is
  </div>
  <div>
    going
  </div>
  <div>
    on?
  </div>
</div>



It changes based on the margins and font-families used, which seems even more arbitrary.
Giving the element in question a width of <=0.8px instead of 1px seems to resolve the issue, but what is the cause? I there a better way to prevent this?
Why use pseudo-elements and not borders?
My intent was creating a design like this:

As far as I know, there is no way to reduce the percentage of width or height a border takes up. That's why I used pseudo elements to achieve the partial-height border.
I do not want to give the element a margin as its background turns a solid color on hover and should take up the full height.

Can you please add a minimal reproductible example ?

you are asking a css question but decided not to show any css in the question?

pseudo elements I use as borders those pseudo elements (before and after) belong to inline elements or block elements?

@BryanDellinger Could you possibly vote to reopen my question? I have provided a minimal demo. Due to an accidental page reload I had to rewrite the question, and simply forgot to put it in the second time around. Stackoverflow will not allow me to repost another one for several days because I received so many downvotes here. This is one of my first questions on this site and thus far, the experience has been rather frustrating.

@Daniel transferred your codepen into SO code snippets, voted to re-open.

voted to reopen, and upvote,

Picture uses different fonts with different size and kerning so please clarify it that is the actual question/answer here?.

They look identical to me (at standard zoom) Is your browser at e.g. 110% zoom? The rendered 1 pixel wide lines generally don't scale consistently with browser zoom.

width: 0.8px is probably a problem. Browsers will round this up/down at their discretion so it's probably rendered as 1px. After all, what does a fraction of a pixel look like?

Perhaps it would be good to know WHY you feel the need to construct borders with pseudo elements; what issue are you trying to solve here in doing that?

@MarkSchultheiss Good point, I have added an explanation to the bottom of the question.

@Paulie_D Yes, possible issues there are the main reason I am looking for a different solution here. As long as the width is >= 0.5px, however, it should not be rounded down to 0 (be invisible), right? My testing thus far has even consistently rendered elements with a width of 0.1px.

@DBS "The rendered 1 pixel wide lines generally don't scale consistently" might be the answer I am looking for. Is there anywhere I can read more about that?
I have no browser zoom enabled, however, I am on a laptop which might be doing some dynamic resolution magic. I would ideally want my elements to be rendered consistently across all devices and zoom levels, but after years of Web Development, I guess that will remain a dream for the time being.

You can do what you want without the reliance on the pseudo elements and give yourself freedom to style as needed.  Here I use a set of grids and put a right margin on some containers as you desire.  Notice how changing the label style does not impact the border and works as expected.
I did not fine-tune the style but this should get you started;


body,
body * {
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.filter-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  place-items: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
  background-color: #00000010;
  color: #004953;
}

.filters {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  place-items: center;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  column-gap: 0.25em;
  border: 1px solid #00000020;
  width: fit-content;
  padding-left: 0.75em;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.filters .filter-item {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 2.5em;
}

.filters .filter-item .filter-item-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 2em;
  grid-template-columns: auto 2em;
  place-items: center;
  column-gap: 0.0em;
}

.b-right {
  border-right: 2px solid #00000020;
  padding-right: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.filter-label {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.serif-fun .filter-label {
  font-family: serif;
}

.mono-fun .filter-label {
  font-family: monotype;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

.mono-fun .icon-container {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
<div class="filter-container">
  <div class="filters">
    <div class="filter-item b-right">
      <div class="filter-item-group">
        <span class="filter-label">Filter</span><span class="icon-container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-funnel" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5zm1 .5v1.308l4.372 4.858A.5.5 0 0 1 7 8.5v5.306l2-.666V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .128-.334L13.5 3.308V2z"/>
</svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item b-right">
      <div class="filter-item-group">
        <span class="filter-label">Category</span><span class="icon-container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-funnel" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5zm1 .5v1.308l4.372 4.858A.5.5 0 0 1 7 8.5v5.306l2-.666V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .128-.334L13.5 3.308V2z"/>
</svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item b-right">
      <div class="filter-item-group">
        <span class="filter-label">Dance</span><span class="icon-container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-funnel" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5zm1 .5v1.308l4.372 4.858A.5.5 0 0 1 7 8.5v5.306l2-.666V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .128-.334L13.5 3.308V2z"/>
</svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item b-last">
      <div class="filter-item-group">
        <span class="filter-label">Sort</span><span class="icon-container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-dice-5" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M13 1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2zM3 0a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v10a3 3 0 0 0 3 3h10a3 3 0 0 0 3-3V3a3 3 0 0 0-3-3z"/>
  <path d="M5.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0m8 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0m0 8a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0m-8 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0m4-4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0"/>
</svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="filters serif-fun">
    <div class="filter-item b-right">
      <div class="filter-item-group">
        <span class="filter-label">Filter</span><span class="icon-container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-funnel" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5zm1 .5v1.308l4.372 4.858A.5.5 0 0 1 7 8.5v5.306l2-.666V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .128-.334L13.5 3.308V2z"/>
</svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item b-right">
      <div class="filter-item-group">
        <span class="filter-label">Category</span><span class="icon-container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-funnel" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5zm1 .5v1.308l4.372 4.858A.5.5 0 0 1 7 8.5v5.306l2-.666V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .128-.334L13.5 3.308V2z"/>
</svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item b-right">
      <div class="filter-item-group">
        <span class="filter-label">Dance</span><span class="icon-container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-funnel" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5zm1 .5v1.308l4.372 4.858A.5.5 0 0 1 7 8.5v5.306l2-.666V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .128-.334L13.5 3.308V2z"/>
</svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item b-last">
      <div class="filter-item-group">
        <span class="filter-label">Sort</span><span class="icon-container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-dice-5" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M13 1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2zM3 0a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v10a3 3 0 0 0 3 3h10a3 3 0 0 0 3-3V3a3 3 0 0 0-3-3z"/>
  <path d="M5.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0m8 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0m0 8a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0m-8 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0m4-4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0"/>
</svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="filters mono-fun">
    <div class="filter-item b-right">
      <div class="filter-item-group">
        <span class="filter-label">Filter</span><span class="icon-container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-funnel" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5zm1 .5v1.308l4.372 4.858A.5.5 0 0 1 7 8.5v5.306l2-.666V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .128-.334L13.5 3.308V2z"/>
</svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item b-right">
      <div class="filter-item-group">
        <span class="filter-label">Category</span><span class="icon-container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-funnel" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5zm1 .5v1.308l4.372 4.858A.5.5 0 0 1 7 8.5v5.306l2-.666V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .128-.334L13.5 3.308V2z"/>
</svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item b-right">
      <div class="filter-item-group">
        <span class="filter-label">Dance</span><span class="icon-container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-funnel" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5zm1 .5v1.308l4.372 4.858A.5.5 0 0 1 7 8.5v5.306l2-.666V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .128-.334L13.5 3.308V2z"/>
</svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item b-last">
      <div class="filter-item-group">
        <span class="filter-label">Sort</span><span class="icon-container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-dice-5" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M13 1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2zM3 0a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v10a3 3 0 0 0 3 3h10a3 3 0 0 0 3-3V3a3 3 0 0 0-3-3z"/>
  <path d="M5.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0m8 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0m0 8a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0m-8 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0m4-4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0"/>
</svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



